# Why doesn't `predict.ksvm` predict the class labels?

Tags: r, svm

I'm trying to figure out the difference in performance between `ksvm` (kernlab) and `svm` (e1071).

I'm using the spam database in the kernlab package.

#### Minimal working example

```
library("kernlab")
data(spam)

##replacing "spam" labels with 1 or -1
type= ifelse(spam[,58]=="spam",1,-1)
spam <- spam[,-58]
spam <- cbind(spam, type)

## create test and training set
spam <- spam[sample(1:4601),] #random permutation
selection <- 1:2300
training <- spam[selection,-58]
training.truth <- spam[selection,58]
test <- spam[-selection, -58]
test.truth <- spam[-selection, 58]

## train a support vector machine
filter <- ksvm(training.truth~.,
               data=training,
               kernel="rbfdot",
               class="C-svc",
               kpar=list(sigma=0.05),C=5)

## predict mail type on the test set
mailtype <- predict(filter,test)

mailtype[1,]  ## returns -0.2459927
```

Why does this return `-0.2459927`, why doesn't it return the label `1` or `-1`?
I tried adjusting some options, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to define `training.truth` as factor, so that `kvsm` predicts classes as the type by default (which is "response"). That is:

```
training.truth <- as.factor(spam[selection,58])
```

with the rest of the code untouched, and then,

```
mailtype <- predict(filter,test)

mailtype[1]
[1] -1
Levels: -1 1
```

Hope it helps.